# MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error

Tags: java, eclipse, atg, eclipse-marketplace

I need help. I use Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) with Java version 1.7.0_271. When trying to open Eclipse Marketplace I get this error log.

I already went to Window > Preferences > General > Network Connection and checked 'Manual', even so, the error remains.

This environment is a bit old, but it's for my job as I use an old framework called 'ATG'. I hope I get help, as plugins make my job a lot easier.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

```
Cannot complete request to [https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&client.version=1.5.4.v20170222-1921&os=linux&ws=gtk&nl=pt_BR&java.version=1.8.0_292&product=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product&product.version=4.6.3.M20170301-0400&runtime.version=3.12.0.v20160606-1342&platform.version=4.6.3.v20170301-0400:](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&client.version=1.5.4.v20170222-1921&os=linux&ws=gtk&nl=pt_BR&java.version=1.8.0_292&product=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product&product.version=4.6.3.M20170301-0400&runtime.version=3.12.0.v20160606-1342&platform.version=4.6.3.v20170301-0400:) 

Unable to read repository at [https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&client.version=1.5.4.v20170222-1921&os=linux&ws=gtk&nl=pt_BR&java.version=1.8.0_292&product=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product&product.version=4.6.3.M20170301-0400&runtime.version=3.12.0.v20160606-1342&platform.version=4.6.3.v20170301-0400](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&client.version=1.5.4.v20170222-1921&os=linux&ws=gtk&nl=pt_BR&java.version=1.8.0_292&product=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product&product.version=4.6.3.M20170301-0400&runtime.version=3.12.0.v20160606-1342&platform.version=4.6.3.v20170301-0400).

Unable to read repository at [https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&client.version=1.5.4.v20170222-1921&os=linux&ws=gtk&nl=pt_BR&java.version=1.8.0_292&product=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product&product.version=4.6.3.M20170301-0400&runtime.version=3.12.0.v20160606-1342&platform.version=4.6.3.v20170301-0400](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&client.version=1.5.4.v20170222-1921&os=linux&ws=gtk&nl=pt_BR&java.version=1.8.0_292&product=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product&product.version=4.6.3.M20170301-0400&runtime.version=3.12.0.v20160606-1342&platform.version=4.6.3.v20170301-0400).

No trusted certificate found
```

Comment: Note: You generally don't have to use an old Eclipse just to work with an old framework. The current Eclipse still supports developing using old versions of Java.

Comment: I guess it is caused by running Eclipse with Java 7 these days. Is ATG just a framework used as dependency in your project or an Eclipse plugin, e.g. [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/ATGInstallGuide/html/s0108installingatgdevelopmenttoolsfor01.html)? Did you tried a current Eclipse?